Can you run a uROS Server Service with a read and write callback?
So right now I'm working on a project thats porting uROS into an existing FreeRTOS project. All the test's with publishers and subscribers are working fine, but I ran into a snag with the Services. The current architecture has 4 main tasks, one that handles IO pins (IO taks), one that handles system power (Sys Task), one that communicates with the host computer (Coms Task), and one the handles LED animations (Prop Task). I have uROS living in Coms. When I'm publishing and subscribing, I'm able to use FreeRTOS Queue's to pass data from one task to another. However the uROS service server callback is for receiving a message and sending a response in the same function. That means I can't send data to the other tasks. This becomes an issue for the IO and LED properties requests from the host computer.
TLDR; is there a way to seperate out the Request and Response callbacks in uROS services?
Something like what's below (this is not actual code, just a mock up)
void io_srv_callback_read_req(const void* req){
    my_interfaces__srv__IOControl_Request* req_in = (my_interfaces__srv__IOControl_Request*) req;
    Event_Send(COM_Task,IO_Task,req_in);
    return;
}

/* In the COM Task I call Event_Recieved(&my_res); asynchrounously when anything is in the queue
   If my_res matches the request sent to IO task then call io_srv_callback_write_res(my_res)*/
   
void io_srv_callback_write_res(void* res){
    my_interfaces__srv__IOControl_Response* res_out =(my_interfaces__srv__IOControl_Response*)my_res;
    return;
}

